# Construct a blocking set in a chessboard barring rectangles from it

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose we have a chessboard with *m*n* unit squares. Consider the rectangular polyominoes of the shape *a*b* within it, where *a* is less than or equals to *m* and *b* is less than or equals to *n*. A subset of unit squares **S** of the board is called a blocking set of type *(a,b)* if any such polyomino(and its rotation) intersects with at least one unit square in **S**. Now I want to find an algorithm to construct a blocking set that has the least number of unit squares.

I've asked the same problem for a closed formula of the size of the smallest blocking set in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571893/rectangle-exclusion-by-monominoes) and hopefully this time the solution would be easier.

---

Although there have been some answers now, I think I have the obiligation to make the question more clear. Let me give a concrete example. Suppose our chessboard is of size *6*6*. At this momemt let's consider the case *a=2,b=3*. For example, the yellow blocks in the following picture are two *2*3* rectanglular polyonimoes on it.

[image: rectangular polyominoes]

Now think about the set **S** of red unit squares below

[image: a blocking set]

It is easy to check that any *2*3* rectangular polyomino on the board must intersect with the **S**, and by the pigeonhole principle any blocking set must include at least 6 unit squares, so **S** is also a smallest one. Of course **S** is not unique in the sense that one can find another smallest blocking set that is not identical to it. To be precise, what I am looking for is an algorithm to construct **one** smallest blocking set on the board just like the red set **S** above, but to a general quadruple (*m,n,a,b*). I hope this explanation works.

Comment: I just dont fully understand the question. Can you be more descriptive? Can you give an example of input/output?

Comment: PS: I do however fully understand the question in MSE, is it exactly same one but with polyomino?

Comment: @libik Sorry about that. I've added an example now.

Answer (score 0):

A standard dynamic programming solution is to keep a set of "minimum cost by profile sticking up past this row."  Unfortunately there are `max(a, b)^m` such profiles possible so it won't scale well to large rectangles.

However as one simplification, we can slide each rectangle as far over and down as possible.  This does reduce the number of profiles some.

With that said, here is running Python code for this problem.  Note, though, that even something as simple as finding out that `blocking(11,10, 4,3)` is `120` will take some time to run.  That's both because of how much data it has to track, and how much temporary garbage it creates.

```
def blocking (m, n, a, b):
    # Small optimization.
    if (m < n):
        (m, n) = (n, m)
    # We start before with a row with nothing sticking up, of cost 0 to get here.
    last_solutions = {
        tuple([0 for i in range(m)]): 0
        }
    # Now advance one row, n times.
    for i in range(n):
        next_solutions = {}
        for (profile, cost) in last_solutions.items():
            carried_profile = tuple([i-1 for i in profile])
            for (new_profile, incremental_cost) in advance_row(carried_profile, a, b):
                if tuple(reversed(new_profile)) < new_profile:
                    # By symmetry we only need to look at one of these.  Look at the other!
                    pass
                elif new_profile in next_solutions:
                    next_solutions[new_profile] = min(next_solutions[new_profile], cost + incremental_cost)
                else:
                    next_solutions[new_profile] = cost + incremental_cost
        last_solutions = next_solutions
    return min(last_solutions.values())

def advance_row(profile, a, b, p=0):
    if len(profile) <= p:
        # We reached the end.  Yield it.
        yield (profile, 0)
    else:
        if 0 < profile[p]:
            # It is OK to put no block here.
            for (next_profile, cost) in advance_row(profile, a, b, p+1):
                yield (next_profile, cost)
        area = a * b
        if profile[p] < b:
            # We might place a block a x b here
            new_profile = add_in_rectangle(profile, a, b, p)
            for (next_profile, cost) in advance_row(new_profile, a, b, p+1):
                yield (next_profile, cost+area)
        if profile[b] < b:
            # We might place a block b x a here
            new_profile = add_in_rectangle(profile, b, a, p)
            for (next_profile, cost) in advance_row(new_profile, a, b, p+1):
                yield (next_profile, cost+area)

# Creates a copy of the profile with a block of length a, height b
# filled in starting at position p
def add_in_rectangle(profile, a, b, p):
    # Make a copy
    new_profile = [x for x in profile]
    for i in range(p, min(p + b, len(profile))):
        new_profile[i] = max(profile[i], a)
    return tuple(new_profile)
```

Comment: What is blocking(m,n,a,b) stand for? I am afraid either I totally missed your point in the answer, or you may have some misunderstandings about the question. Since someone told me that the problem description was not quite clear in the first edition, I'll apology for that if that did mislead you.

Comment: @Phil.Z I was thinking blocking off and covering everything.  So I did misunderstand what you wanted.  The math version of your question talking about tilings helped send me on that course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second approach that is likely a lot faster, but I won't take the time to code it.  However because it is unrelated to my other solution, I'll make it a separate answer.

Consider the set of outlines of partial tilings as the nodes of a graph.  From each one you can construct a set of edges which is the result of adding a rectangle whose bottom edge covers the left-most empty square on the bottom row that is not completely filled in.  (This will give `a + b` edges to each node.)

Now construct an `A*` search from the node which is nothing there to the node that is completely filled.  From any node the estimated cost is the smallest multiple of `a*b` that is greater than the number of empty squares.

If, as seems to be often the case, an optimal tiling can be produced by a greedy search, this search will quickly discover that and give you an answer.  It only needs to backtrack if this is not true.

Even if it does backtrack, the fact that you keep track of which nodes you've been to will give you the benefits of a DP solution, likely with better pruning of the possibilities that you have to analyze.